# Is it possible to change an UIActivityIndicatorView color to black in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiactivityindicatorview

I want to change an activity indicator color gray/white to black. Is it possible to change the color to black? If yes, please guide me or give some sample code.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

You can use the `.color` property in order to change the `UIActivityIndicatorView` color, e.g.:

```
// Objective-C
activityIndicator.color = [UIColor greenColor];

// Swift
activityIndicator.color = .green
```

Note that `.color` is only [available from iOS 5](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiactivityindicatorview/1622836-color).

Comment: This does not work. This changes the colour of the ActivityIndicator text and not the ActivityIndicator spinning Icon that OP is asking about.

Comment: @AlexHarvey - it changed the icon for me. What is your code?

Comment: In Xcode 6 (but perhaps even earlier), it is possible to change the color and size of the activity view directly in IB.

Comment: I'm using Xcode 7.1.1 for iOS9.1 and it works well in IB, changing the color of the activity indicator graphic itself.

Answer (score 5):

It is very easy in Swift 5

```
@IBOutlet weak var loadingIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!       //Declare the UIActivityIndicatorView

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   loadingIndicator.style = .medium     //Just change the indicator Style
   loadingIndicator.color = .black      //and change what is your indicator color
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To use a standard system color:

```
activityIndicator.color = .green
```

To use a custom RGBA color

```
activityIndicator.color = UIColor(displayP3Red: 255/255, green: 150/255, blue: 181/255, alpha: 255/255)
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend doing the following:

1. `UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.whiteLarge` to make the spinner bigger
2. pick a color
3. pick a backgroundColor to increase contrast

   ```
   var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.whiteLarge)
   activityIndicator.color = UIColor.<YOUR DESIRED COLOR>
   activityIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.<YOUR DESIRED BACKGROUND COLOR>
   self.view.addSubview(self.activityIndicator)
   ```

Comment: Your answer is valid, but it also adds code that is not relevant to the scope of the question (e.g. `hidesWhenStopped`, `center`,...) 

Answer (score 0):

You can switch between `.gray`, `.white` and `.whiteLarge` by using the [`.activityIndicatorViewStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiactivityindicatorview/1622847-activityindicatorviewstyle) property.